# how does the bind() function work in JAX when making a new primitive?

Tags: python, jax

While I am checking and studying the jax code, I see lots of `bind()` usage. I wanted to know how it works and what's its functionality. Here is one of the [example](https://github.com/google/jax/blob/main/tests/api_test.py#L1623).

```
def test_unimplemented_interpreter_rules(self):
    foo_p = core.Primitive('foo')
    def foo(x):
      return foo_p.bind(x)
```

Comment: Because the core primitives are not necessarily regular Python functions, then can't just do a simple `foo_p(x)`.  The `bind` call simulates that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of `bind()` as essentially equivalent to calling the function represented by the primitive. But because JAX primitives are designed to work with its abstract evaluation and transformation framework, binding a primitive is a bit more complicated than just calling a function, because the meaning of binding a primitive changes depending on the context. For example:

- in normal, non-transformed code, it will result in a call to the primitive's `impl` rule
- during general abstract evaluation like `jax.make_jaxpr` or `jax.eval_shape`, it will call the primitive's abstract evaluation rule
- inside `jax.vmap`, it will result in a call to the primitive's batching rule
- inside `jax.grad`, it will result in a call to the primitive's autodiff-related rules (jvp and/or transpose)

If you want to understand more about the details of JAX primitives and how they interact with JAX tracing, abstract evaluation, and transformations, a good resource is [Autodidax: JAX core from scratch](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autodidax.html), which walks through creating a simplified version of JAX from the ground up.